# Connet to ethernet via internet Ubutnu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ethernet

I need to connect to the internet to reinstall some packages. I am in emergency/recovery mode and I cannot boot
the output of ifconfig

[image]

Comment: Please do not have pictures of text include the text in the question.

Comment: This image looks like a tty login (non-GUI). The OP cannot copy/paste from this terminal, so an image is quite acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to:

1. mount rootfs read and write by

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
2. connect Ethernet cable
3. get IP address from DHCP server

   ```
   dhclient enp0s31f6
   ```
4. do ordinary steps with APT - like

   ```
   apt-get update
   apt-get install --reinstall ...
   ```